# need sqlite data content compare

Tags: windows, gratis, database, comparison, sqlite

I need a free sqlite tool for comparing two sqlite database table values.
I've used SQLiteSync, but it's not good at it.
any more better graphical tool?

Comment: Did I understand it correctly that you have two SQLite databases with the same table, and want to compare those? If so, would dumping the tables (e.g. to CSV) and comparing them with a text diff tool be acceptable?

Comment: it would be better some graphical tools inside the program. want to highlight differenct values

Comment: There are graphical diff-tools for text files (think e.g. of WinDiff). Question remains: Is it sufficient to *show* differences (then this method would easily work) – or must immediate actions follow (e.g. you must descide which value to change in which database and do it straight away)?

Comment: up to now, just difference colored in good graphics is ok, if any open source tool that I can develope it, it will be good too

Comment: I haven't used WinDiff for a while now, but ,a few days ago, I used Beyond Compare to diff two CSV files, and it represented them nicely with columns. Take a look at https://www.scootersoftware.com/vbulletin/filedata/fetch?id=76392&d=1442845839  Btw, great question. I have marked it as favo(u)rite & hope that you get a good answer :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't used this, just DuckDucklGo'ed it, but what about

> [KS DB Merge Tools for SQLite](https://db-merge-tools.net/sqlite-diff-merge-overview.html) is an easy to use diff & merge tool for SQLite databases. This tool allows to compare and import/export database objects and data between two database files. It can run in two modes - basic free version and paid Pro mode that provides extended functionality and overcomes limitations of the free version.
>
> Free version allows to compare table definitions, diff and merge views, indexes and triggers. It also provides basic data diff and merge facilities, allowing to compare table contents, merge the whole records or only required columns for chosen records.
>
> Pro version has a number of significant functional improvements, such as batch data diff, query result diff and more. In addition it has a lot of small nice refinements that will make your work much more productive.

[image]